# Send a message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a strange behaviour of a mail function with CodeIgniter that I try to explain but cannot figure out or reason for it.

My function is like

```
function _send_email($type, $email, &$data)
    {
        //original
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject("Test Message");
        $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));
        $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-txt', $data, TRUE));
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

This is basically inspired from Tank Auth library

### Case where the function works fine

When I use this function inside a method like below the mail is sent :

```
function comment($postid=0){
    $poster = $this->Post->getPoster($postid); # Gets the Post author records
    $notifythisuser = $poster[0]['email']; # Gets the Post author's email
    $datacode = array('posttitle' => $this->input->post('posttitle',true),
                    'posttext' => $this->input->post('posttext',true)
                    );
    $this->_send_email('commentadded', $notifythisuser, $datacode);
    $this->post->comment();
}
```

### Case where the function dos not work

Now, it is more reasonable to notify the user after the comment being sent

so the function would be

```
function comment($postid=0){
    $poster = $this->Post->getPoster($postid); # Gets the Post author records
    $notifythisuser = $poster[0]['email']; # Gets the Post author's email
    $datacode = array('posttitle' => $this->input->post('posttitle',true),
                    'posttext' => $this->input->post('posttext',true)
                    );

    if ($this->input->post('posttitle') ){
         $this->post->comment();
         $this->_send_email('commentadded', $notifythisuser, $datacode);
         }
}
```

Nothing  complicated I just rearranged the code so that the notification is sent after the comment is posted, the `comment()` function is very basic it is just a function that do an `insert` in a table of comment

I tried to debug the mail function, no errors sent, no log generated, something is wrong but I cant tell what

any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if there is POST data with the name `posttitle`? if there is, did you check if `comment()` successfully executed?

Comment: Yes, I did, for some reason out of the if bloc everything seems to work, but once in the if bloc data seems to be lost strangely

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory:

Codeigniter's input class is stripping away the xss-like characters in `posttitle` and it may be leaving you with an empty string. And then PHP kicks in with its weak typing by assuming that the empty string is false.

```
if(""){
   //THIS WILL NEVER EXECUTE BECAUSE PHP IS AWESOME
}
```

The solution, use strongly typed comparison

```
if($this->input->post('posttitle') !== false){
   $this->post->comment();
   $this->_send_email('commentadded', $notifythisuser, $datacode);
}
```